# How to find the module?

Tags: java, java-module

[image]

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: E:\workspace\javaGarbageCode\lessonDesign\test9\test9\target\classes
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package com.eg.test9.controller.CalendarController not found in module
```

It looks like there are some problems in the module-info.java. How to solve this path problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `Package com.eg.test9.controller.CalendarController not found` ← You don’t have a **package** with that name.  You have a class with that name, but not a package with that name.  You can only open packages in a module descriptor, not individual classes.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But There still have some errors in the project. I followed your advice but still reported mistakes like this.Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module com.eg.test9 not found